# Angular using d3plus chokes on coffee

Tags: angular, d3.js, d3plus

I want to use d3plus in an Angular project. Mainly for its clever text wrapping.

I made a `d3.lib.ts` file with:

```
export * from 'd3';
export * from 'd3plus';
```

The 'd3plus' is red in IntelliJ. I've npm installed d3, d3plus, @types/d3 and @types/d3plus. That might be overkill, but surely something here should work.

When I build, I get:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/d3plus/src/init.coffee 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '#' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
> ###*
| # @class d3plus
| ###
ERROR in ./node_modules/d3plus/src/libs.coffee 1:26
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:26)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
> window.d3       = require "d3"
| window.topojson = require "topojson"
```

It seems Angular is trying to interpret coffeescript, but I have no idea why it would do that. Why is it not simply ignoring that and using the d3plus.js in the folder above it?

And how do I get this working? Is this the right approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try npm i d3plus@next , it will install remaining packages.

Comment: I now get this error: `./node_modules/d3plus/index.js
Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\me\projects\project\node_modules\d3plus\index.js'`. It seems to have ended up in a /build subfolder instead.

Answer (score 1):

I will caveat my answer with - I am using d3plus for the text wrap feature.  I could not use the `d3plus.textwrap` function as posted in some blogs.  I deduced from the information online that in d3 v4 separate d3plus packages must be used.  For textwrap for example, we have to use the d3plus-text package and then access the textwrap function as follows:

```
new d3plus-text.textWrap()...
```